# Passing a variable from an activity to a class

Tags: java, android

I am knew to Android.
How do i pass a static variable from one activity to a class.
I have a list of buttons and when i click one button, i want to open a new activity and at thye same time, pass a variable relating to that class. I have tried using shared preferences but in vain. The string variable i would like to is is called url. This is the code i have from the class

```
public class AppConstant {

    public static final String BASE_URL = url;

}
```

The BASE_URL will be used in other classes that is why it is static and i want it to stay that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since other solutions haven't worked for you, here is something a bit different:
Make a saparate file named "ext" or something. inside make a public abstract class like so:

```
public interface ext {
    HashMap <String, String> myHash = new HashMap<>();
}
```

This way myHash will be created when the app is launched and will live as long as the app does so when you move from activity to activity, you can add values this way and access them in the next activity:

```
ext.myHash.put("BASE_URL", url);
```

Answer (score 2):

shortest way would be to remove `final` keyword

```
public static String BASE_URL = url;
```

this will allow you to write to this field from any method in your app

```
AppConstant.BASE_URL = "abc";
```

note that `AppConstant` isn't proper name for such usage, `BASE_URL` isn't constant...

btw. keeping data in `static` field is a veeery poor aproach, don't do this... use `Bundle` for passing data between `Activities`, IPC communication (binding) for `Services`, `SharedPreferences`, `SQLiteDatabase` and probably few other methods...

Comment: removing the final keyword won't help, i want to know how to retrieve value into the class, even if i remove it i still do not have the value

Answer (score 1):

If it's static it shouldn't be in a Activity,

I assume you mean accessing a static variable from an Activity?

If so you can simply call `AppConstant.BASE_URL`  in your Activity, if it is shown in red press Control+Enter to fix the import in Android Studio.

On the other hand, passing a variable from an activity to a class can simply be done via methods. So just call a method in the activity and use a String as a parameter like so

```
Otherclass.doSomethingWithString(urlInYourActivity)
```

But I assume the thing I mentioned at the start is what you want to do

Comment: Nop that is not it, i want to pass a variable from activity to a class, to retrive it to other classes i already know

Comment: Alright, so why don't you hardcode it in a normal class? Is it retrieved in a activity?

Comment: no it is retrieved in another class, and i cannot hard code it as it should change for every button clicked

Comment: If it isn't retrieved in a activity via network calls or something it shouldn't be too hard, if you update your question with the source of the data I can help you better